# Autodesk Forgetoolkit - AR VR

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk

Is Server V2 online? I'm still getting a result of "created" when posting a arkit translation job followed by error 404 when I try to get the manifest. Using developer-api-beta.autodesk.io

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Yes, the server was updated yesterday - if you want us to debug the issue, we would need a bit more information such as the URN and sceneID your are processing.

Comment: Thanks for your response @cyrille. I managed to get a small Revit model through the process and into Unity without any errors. I tried with a larger Navisworks model and I get error 504 when attempting to get the mainfest. 

URN: dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZWljX2J1Y2tldC9USElFU1NfU0VTJTIwV29ya3Nob3AlMjBWNC5ud2Q

SceneID: Thiess_test

Comment: I see you successfully get the manifest on the 12th using Postman. On the 10th, I see you you got a 404 error because you requested the manifest before it was ready. I am curious if you did check for the progress endpoint or setup a callback to be notified when it is ready.

Answer (score 1):

JovEIC, cyrille,

Following this question, I keep receiving 
**msg": "must be a valid Bearer token for the requested resource (TK1-003)"** 
from v2 server developer-api-beta.autodesk.io

Any advice please ?

Thanks

Comment: @cyrille I'm also seeing this issue within the past few days. Do you have any insight on what the cause might be?